# Convert Observable<Observable<{t1: T1, t2: T2}>> to Observable<{t1: T1, t2: T2}[]>

Tags: stream, rxjs, observable

I have two Observable: obs1 and obs2

- **obs1** is of type `Observable<T1[]>` (retrieved from a
  `this.service1.getT1Arr()` function)
- **obs2** is of type `Observable<T2>`
  (retrieved from a `this.service2.getT2(t1: T1)` function)

I want to create an **obs3** with the type:

```
Observable<{t1: T1, t2: T2}[]>
```

My current problem is that the function I am using to retrieve obs2 takes as argument an object of type T1, so I need to follow these steps:

1. Retrieve each object of type T1 from the T1[] array
2. For each of this object retrieve its
   corresponding object T2
3. Construct an object made of those two objects

Currently I have the following code:

```
obs3 = this.service1.getT1Arr().flatMap((t1Arr: T1[]) => {
    return t1Arr.map((t1) => {
        return this.service2.getT2(t1).map((t2: T2) => {
            return {
                t1: t1
                t2: t2
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But I got the error

```
Observable<Observable<{t1: T1, t2: T2}>> is not assignable to 
Observable<{t1: T1, t2: T2}[]>
```

So my question is: How can I keep my array type throughout the process and not lose it in exchange of an Observable?

I already looked at combining operators such as *concat()*, *merge()* and also the transforming operator *switchMap()* but the problem I have is that I don't have two parallels stream but one stream that is created from another stream.

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: Did you try making the signature specific? i.e. 
`.flatMap((t1Arr: T1[]): Array<{T1, t2}> => {...}`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `flatMap` is designed to flatten *one* level of nesting. You actually have two because you are returning an `Array` of `Observables` from the selector function. You need an extra layer of flattening:

```
const obs3: Observable<{T1, T2}[]> = 
  this.service1.getT1Arr().flatMap((t1Arr: T1[]) => {
    // Lift the t1Array into an Observable<T1>
    return Observable.from(t1Array)
      // Flatten the results of calling service2
      .concatMap(
        // Returns Observable<T2>
        t1 => this.service2.getT2(t1),
        // Use the result selector to map to your desired structure
        (t1, t2) => ({t1, t2})
      )
      // Gather the results back up Observable<{T1, T2}[]>
      .toArray();
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response! So I tried it but unfortunately it's not working. The type is now correct thanks to your answer but when I am subscribing to it I get nothing even if I see that my t1Arr is of length 6. What is also weird is that apparently I enter into the concatMap only once, whereas I should enter in it 6 times in my case (I tried replacing concatMap with flatMap and I enter 6 times as expected but I have still no result when subscribing). Do you know where it could come from?

Comment: Make sure that `getT2()` and `getT1Arr()` Observables complete. If you are only entering `concatMap` once then that means the inner Observables aren't completing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert a stream of list items to stream of individual items using flatMap , then for each item t1 , do another fltaMap call to fetch t2 . Then use map to combine them . See if this works for you

```
this.service1.getT1Arr()
    .flatMap(t1Arr: T1[] => Observable.from(t1Arr))
    .flatMap((t1 : T1)=> this.service2.getT2(t1)
         .map((t2:T2)=> {t1: t1, t2: t2})
     );
```

If you wish to get the result in single array instead of stream you can add `.toArray()` after last flatMap .