# Flatten nested Observables with outer array without inner subscribe (RxJS)

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, nested, observable

Given the following TypeScript functions, that do async HTTP-Calls:

```
public retrieveAllMembersIdsFromGroup(groupId: string): Observable<string[]>
public retrieveMember(memberId: string): Observable<Member>
```

How to combine this in one function to get all members (Observable)?

```
public retieveAllMembersFromGroup(groupId: string): Observable<Member[]>
```

For example I want to have something like this:

```
public retieveAllMembersFromGroup(groupId: string): Observable<Member[]> {
return this.retrieveAllMembersIdsFromGroup(groupId).pipe(
      map((membersIds: string[]) => {
        //some magic here to call this.retrieveMember(memberId)
        return //Observable<Member[]>;
      })
    );
}
```

If possible I do not want to subscribe to retrieveAllMembersIdsFromGroup, so as not to have to process the ids manually.
What is the best solution?

Comment: A similar problem is solved here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44461271/convert-observableobservablet1-t1-t2-t2-to-observablet1-t1-t2-t2
But unfortunately I cannot transfer that solution to my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follwoing solution works for me:

```
public retrieveAllMembersFromGroup(groupId: string): Observable<Member[]> {
    return from(this.retrieveAllMemberIdsFromGroup(groupId)).pipe(
      mergeMap((membersIds: string[]) => {
        const members$: Observable<Member>[] = [];
        membersIds.forEach((memberId: string) => {
          members$.push(this.retrieveMember(memberId));
        });
        return combineLatest(members$);
      })
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not fully understand what magic you are looking for but maybe this could work for you?

```
public retrieveAllMembersFromGroup(groupId: string): Observable<Member[]> {
    return this.retrieveAllMemberIdsFromGroup(groupId).pipe(
      concatMap((memberId: string) => {
        return this.retrieveMember(memberId);
      })
    );
}
```

Note that I also changed some names as they were either spelt wrong or weird grammar.

Comment: This will not work, because retrieveAllMemberIdsFromGroup() returns an array.

Comment: @MaikKwi `concatMap` emits each item in the array and performs `this.retrieveMember(memberId)` on each `memberId`, what you get back from `retrieveAllMembersFromGroup` is an array of members. Is that not what you want?

Comment: Well... the error with the use of concatMap in your example is quite clear:
Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type 'string'

Comment: @MaikKwi OK I made this example which works https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-9lhhbt?file=index.ts, basically you need to convert your response from the first function to a sequence which you can then call concatMap on followed by toArray (without it the subscribe will fire 3 times instead of 1).

Comment: Your example works fine. But you transfer an array with "from", so it results in Observable<string>. But I have an Observable<string[]>. So how to transfer my Observable<string[]> to Observable<string>?

Comment: @MaikKwi I'm not sure I understand why your code isn't working. Do you have to do this maybe? https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-t6jfky?file=index.ts

Comment: Thanks, it looks good. But one thing does not work for me: When I use toArray() nothing is emmitted. Without toArray it works, but the return-type is not correct. Probably the difference is, that my two functions (that returns the Observables) are HTTP-Calls. Any idea, why toArray() is not working in that case?

Comment: @MaikKwi Hmm. Sounds really odd, http or not they're still just observables. Could it be that you get no member ids back from the function and the array is empty therefore nothing is emitted? If not I really have no idea.

Comment: No... ids are there. Without the toArray()-call every member is emmitted... so the data is correctly determinded.

Comment: @MaikKwi Odd. If you can get a working stackblitz together that I can debug with I can investigate but without it my hands are pretty tied unfortunately.

Comment: I modified your project to have a delay in your function... that should work like a http-call:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-xtmprv